# Deleting .libs Folder from Python Libraries for Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, libraries

I'm deleting folders from Python libraries to fit the 250 MB Unzipped limit.

When I install numpy and scipy. I have two folders numpy.libs and scipy.libs. These contain .so files. Can I safely delete these such that the library remains functional?

Comment: Why not use container lambda which gives you 10GB of space, not only 250 MB?

Comment: That was going to be plan B. I'm currently at 280MB. I figured I could prune 30MB more.

Comment: Numpy and scipy layers are provided by aws. Why do you need to create your own?

Comment: Either way the 250MB limit is including the layer size, right?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting these .libs won't work, they are required.

However, you can find prepared layers (load via ARN) for some popular packages, which are optimized & compressed. For example for `numpy + sklearn` checkout this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/model-zoo/scikit-learn-lambda/blob/master/layers.csv) to find the ARN that matches your python version and region.